# View documentation of Gradle depedencies

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else. I have a Gradle project set on Intellij for working with TormentFX (in kotlin that is). I would like to view the documentation of said library with Ctrl+Q for example. Is there any way of making this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely you need to have the sources downloaded, which should be done automatically unless they're not available?

Answer (score 0):

As for the solution for this, restarting Intellij worked and added the jars to the project. If anyone could improve on why this worked, while providing a more definitive solution the stage is yours.

Comment: Manually adding jars is not required (not recommend either), because it fetches the sources packages, while they're available in the repository. Most likely you've just synced the project with the Gradle files... which is such a basic task, that this Q&A might not be too helpful for others.